# UWP DatePicker Update Value on DatePart-Changed, do not require "OK" button

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, uwp, datepicker

Using either Xamarin.Forms (for UWP), or pure UWP, How do I force the Date value binding to update as soon as a date-part is changed, without requiring the user clicks the "OK"/done/checkmark button?

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

[image: DatePicker Whoas]

Answer (score 1):

The `DatePicker` template allows you only to change how the control looks like when it is not in the picker mode, but rather when it displays the picked date: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299121.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So basically you would have to make a new `DatePicker` from the scratch to achieve that.